# add event to action listener without deleting default action?

Tags: java

I would like to make it so that when i close my GUI it will run a method in my main class but then also close after?

please help thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Java Swing:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Project Planner");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            exitProcedure();
        }
    });
```

.

```
public void exitProcedure() {
    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Just add what you want to do before the dispose method.

Answer (score 0):

Try an implementation of `WindowAdapter` in GUI's `addWindowListener()` method.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to register `WindowListener` to the associated `JFrame`. And override the `windowClosing()` method.

**EDIT** 
for choosing a String randomly out of an String array you can use [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) API .For Example here is an array of `String` and each time the `JFrame` is closed , a `String` is picked out randomly out of this array and printed in method `callMeBeforeExit`.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Random;
class WorkBeforeClose extends  JFrame
{
    String[] strings = {
                            "Hello",
                            "World",
                            "Java",
                            "OOPs"
                        };
    public void showGUI()
    {
        setTitle("Close me");
        getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Close me"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
            {
                callMeBeforeExit();
                System.exit(0);//Don't write this line if you don't want your program to exit
            }
        });
        setSize(200,200);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private void callMeBeforeExit()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = random.nextInt(strings.length - 1);//Defines the Range of numbers to be chosen randomly.
        System.out.println(strings[i]);
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                WorkBeforeClose wbc = new WorkBeforeClose();
                wbc.showGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: another question is that i want a string to be picked at random and then placed in a system.out.println? how do i do this, thanks

Comment: @JoshuaBaron You have those `Strings` stored in an `array` of `String`?

Comment: @JoshuaBaron: Watch the Edited Answer.